# Logout all users using forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

Is it possible to logout all currently logged on users using forms authentication?

Comment: If you really want to do this, you can indicate in a table associated to the user that they need to be logged out the very next time they get to the site and their authentication cookie still exist?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in way but you can do it yourself without too much trouble.  There is a short discussion on it @ http://forums.asp.net/p/1399478/3021694.aspx.  Personally, I'd go with the profile value.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly you can reload the web application using `System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain()`, this will - as a side effect - kick out all the users (it should invalidate session and login data).